# ICU: What does NFD and NFC mean?

Tags: icu, transliteration

I found a snippet which reads

`Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();`

...and is supposed to make arbitrary string well fitting into a URL.

So, I guess the things between the semicolons are something like "commands" which are to be executed, but what particularly does NDF and NFC stand for? I really did find nothing even in the official documentation...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/charmod-norm/#normalization_forms

Comment: oy thanks; you should have posted that as an answer for I can accept it.. what should I do?

Comment: If that link does not help you write your own answer then I'll have to apologize.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a good page, though.

Comment: @AdrianFöder where in the official documentation did you look? Asking so I can improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [ICU transliterators](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-General) and the linked page on [TR15 normalization forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) for complete examples.

> Normalization Form D (NFD)    Canonical Decomposition
>
> Normalization Form C (NFC)    Canonical Decomposition,
>   followed by Canonical Composition
>
> Normalization Form KD (NFKD)  Compatibility Decomposition
>
> Normalization Form KC (NFKC)  Compatibility Decomposition,
>   followed by Canonical Composition